# Changing hue of CGImage using iPhone SDK

Tags: ios4, cgimage, color-space

Is there a way to change the hue of a CGImage using the iPhone SDK? I've been trying to get this to work but haven't been able to figure it out. How do I go about accessing and modifying the hue associated with each pixel of a CGImage? Can anyone help me with this. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone provide code that translates RGB values of an image to HSV. I am a novice when it comes to Image Processing using the iPhone and haven't been able to make it work successfully. I've converted a UIImage to a CGImageRef using the [image CGImage] function and converted the image to NSData using (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef)). I'm not sure what I need to do after this to access the pixel values or convert the data from an image in RGB to HSV. Can someone help me with this. I've been struggling with it for over a week.

Comment: Can anyone help with this? I've found a couple of posts but am still having a problem implementing this.